# SARS ADCs where BW >> SPS or SPS >> BW

Tags: adc

I was looking at two ADCs, the [ADS8568](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbas543) and [AD7606B](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7606B.pdf) and came by a rather curious design decision for both.

**ADS8568**
[image]
[image]

**AD7606B**

800ksps per channel
[image]

There's quite a mismatch between the sample rate and the bandwidth of each ADC. The ADS8568 has a bandwidth wildly larger than its sample rate, whereas the AD7606B goes in the other direction where it's sample rate is wildly larger than its bandwidth.

Isn't this kind of a waste? I understand sampling up to (a somewhat arbitrary) 32x times faster than the bandwidth, but these two ADC swing farther than that (and do so in both directions).

The only *intentional* reason I can think of the bandwidth of the ADS8568 being so much larger than its sample rate is for undersampling but is undersampling really common enough for the ADC to be designed with that in mind? This seems unlikely to me though. It seems much more likely to me that SARs ADCs in general just have really high bandwidths relative to their sample rates with little effort since the sampling capacitor just grabs whatever is on the line. I saw this with another SARs ADC but have not checked too many though.

Then there's the AD7606B where it seems like a pretty big restriction just to permanently throw in an anti-aliasing filter to clamp its bandwidth to 32x slower than its sample rate. This one is the bigger mystery to me.

Comment: Fix the links in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh That's weird. How did they end up getting replaced with the images?

Comment: @Andyaka Fixed.

Comment: It's probably related to the analogue signal acquisition time (a small fraction of the time between conversions).